# select multiple checkboxes and get the values in Python Django

Tags: python, django, checkbox

I have an HTML table and in that, the last column is for checkbox. so when I check to this multiple checkboxes from that column, it should get the selected values and then I want to send this list of values to a python function.

Can anyone please help me on it?

```
<table id="test-datatable" class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>Address</th>
        <th>Occupation</th>
        <th><input name="select_many" id ="select_many" value="1" `type="checkbox"></th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have mentioned Html table, so I am assuming that you are not using Django forms. You can get the selected values in a multiple checkbox by using jquery or javascript.

```
var $selected = $('#select_many');
var value = $.trim($selected.val());
```

Here, 'select_many' is your multiple checkbox id. You will have individual values that were selected in 'value'. Use this code inside  tag. Now, you have the values next thing is to post it to your database. You can use a POST method to pass the value to your Django views. From there, save it to your database. In the question, you referred python function, that would be a Django View. Happy Coding..!!

Comment: Thanks. Can you please tell me where to add this code and how to call it in django view?

Comment: Sneha, were you able to find out where to post this code and how to call it in Django?  I'm having the same problem, i'm not using a form and I need to pass the values using ajax/js.